# put same address middle below authors names sig-alternate.cls

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

How do i make the university address appear below the authors names and in the center ? I need to do this because both authors are having the same address.

This is my existing code

```
\author{
\alignauthor Sean Fogarty\\
       \affaddr{NASA Ames Research Center}\\
       \affaddr{Moffett Field}\\
       \affaddr{California 94035}\\
       \email{fogartys@amesres.org}
% 6th. author
\alignauthor Charles Palmer\\
       \affaddr{NASA Ames Research Center}\\
       \affaddr{Moffett Field}\\
       \affaddr{California 94035}\\
              \email{cpalmer@prl.com}}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) showing the output you present in the image? That way community members can have something to work with without having to recreate something from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is essentially a solution to this posted on [Dan Lazewatsky's latex page](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~lazewatskyd/latex.html).  Adapting it to your example you can write

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\numberofauthors{2}
\author{
\alignauthor Sean Fogarty\\
       \email{fogartys@amesres.org}
\alignauthor Charles Palmer\\
       \email{cpalmer@prl.com}
\end{tabular}\newline\begin{tabular}{c}
       \affaddr{NASA Ames Research Center}\\
       \affaddr{Moffett Field}\\
       \affaddr{California 94035}\\
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

producing

[image: Sample output]